# CSS3 full-width rotate

Tags: css, css-transforms

I would like to rotate a full-width div (from side to side without free space) in which will be some content.

I want the corners on the right side to touch the right side of the page and the corners on the left side to touch the left side of the page. I don't think `width:200%` and `overflow-x:hidden` is the best solution.

How can I achieve this?

Here is an example. Note that the corners don't touch the sides of the page.

```css
.rotated {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  transform: rotate(-6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated"></div>
```

Comment: What is the "bug" exactly?

Comment: I want by that div to touche with both right corners to the right side of the browser (red corners). The same for the left corners.

Answer (score 3):

You might find the [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) `skewY()` helpful. It will skew the element without rotating the corners.

I've also set the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to the top right so that the element doesn't skew off the top of the page.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

.rotated {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-6deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated"></div>
```

For further reference, see the [Skewing and Translating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms#Example.3A_Skewing_and_translating) example at MDN.

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the horizontal proportion with scale, but the content will be scaled as well (as long as you know it you can compensate)

```css
.rotated {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
   transform:  scale(1.2 , 1) rotate(-6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated"></div>
```